# how to serialize a class in an object to string

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have following object `ICoreFileStat`, which on the server side, URI will be a class created using [vscode-uri](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-uri/blob/master/lib/index.ts). How do I convert only `URI` to string recursively?

```
export interface ICoreFileStat extends ICoreBaseStat {
  children?: ICoreFileStat[];
}
export interface ICoreBaseStat {
  resource: URI | string;
  name?: string;
}
```

What I was expecting the URI in the above object will be transformed to `string` like `(file:///index.js)` and it will be a plain object like below.

```
const data = {
children: {
   resource: "///file://tmp"
   children: {
      resource: "///file:/index.js"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, I came up with. But I would like to see others solutions as well.

```
const serialize = (stat: IFileStat) => Object.keys(stat).reduce((result, name) => {
    // console.log(result);
    if (name === 'resource') {
        return result = { ...stat, resource: stat[name].toString() };
    } else if (name === 'children') {
        return { ...result, ...{ children: stat[name].map(child => serialize(child as any)) } }
    }
    else {
        return result
    }
}, {});
```